# p congruent to 1 mod 4 is a sum of square

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

I am studying the proof that if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ then $p$ can be written as a sum of squares. That is one implication of Fermat's two square theorem.

I have stumbled upon this text: https://people.bath.ac.uk/masgcs/book1/amplifications/fermat2sq.pdf

More specifically, it states that:

[image]

I don't understand specifically why in the aforementioned excerpt there exist $c$, $d$ so that $x_1 = x - cm_0$ and $y_1 = y - dm_0$. How can we prove it?

Comment: The point is that a prime of the form $4k+1$ is the sum of TWO squares. Every natural number is the sum of (at most) $4$ squares (Lagrange).

Comment: @Peter understood! But I don't get how we obtain the conditions on $x_1$ and $y_1$...

Comment: We can reduce $x_1$ and $y_1$ modulo $m_0$ without changing the residue of $x_1^2+y_1^2$ modulo $m_0$ and because of the squares we can also take the negative residue (residue minus $m_0$) to ensure that the absolute value is not exceeding $m_0/2$